# Getting Text Between HTML Tags & Replacing Them

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I would like to get text between HTML tags and replacing them dynamically. Considering HTML tags might contain anything (nested HTML tags, comments, etc) I think [DOM Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class is the way to go. However I wasn't able to find any example for my needs. I can only get the text between of specifically selected html tag. I also couldn't find an example to replace selected text.

```
<?php 
// HTML OUTPUT
$html= "<p>Subject,</p>
<h1>H1 title</h1>
<h2>H2 title</h2>
<h3>H2 title</h3>";

// DESIRED OUTPUT
$newHTML "<p>My Fav. Colors;</p>
<h1>Blue</h1>
<h2>Orange</h2>
<h3>Yellow</h3>";
?>
```

Basically I would like to get text from HTML output dynamically (might contain nested HTML tags, comments, javascripts scripts and so on.) and replace them (replaced values will be selected from database) to create new HTML output.

What is the best and elegant way to go? Is [**DOM Document**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class is the tool I need or **Regex** is the way to go?

I will be really glad if you could show me with a small piece of code to understand it clearly.

**P.S.** HTML document in question might be a page on another domain. Such as http://anotherdomain.com/page.html.

Comment: I think it is better to use Dom Parser instead of regular expressions

Comment: Regex can help you replace simple strings without _understanding_ the document you are working on. DOM Document and similar understand the HTML (and also require it to be valid). Depending on the complexity (e.g. comments as you stated), DOM Document seems the way to go. However if you know that there will for example be no second `<h1>` tag inside the first, you could split them and regex it then (it depends how you identify _what_ is to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Considering HTML might contain anything Regex might cause some mistakes. DOM Document seems to be best way but how to get Text between html tags and replace them?

Comment: @Revenant If your text will be in a specific form — for example, you have things like `%subject%` — you could just `str_replace`. I'm not sure that this is the case, though, as it's not clear whether you are generating the initial document.

Comment: @arxanas; Firstly thank you for your comment. HTML document in question might be a page on another domain. Such as http://anotherdomain.com/page.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of DOM.

```
$html= "<p>Subject,</p>
<h1>H1 title</h1>
<h2>H2 title</h2>
<h3>H2 title</h3>";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( '<div>' . $html . '</div>');

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    switch ($node->nodeName) {
        case "p":
            $node->nodeValue = "My Fav. Colors";
            break;
        case "h1":
            $node->nodeValue = "Blue";
            break;
        case "h2":
            $node->nodeValue = "Orange";
            break;
        case "h3":
            $node->nodeValue = "Yellow";
            break;          
    }
}
echo $doc->saveXML($doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Teno. Unfortunately I don't know if I will replace `p` tag with `May Fav. Colors` text. It is depending on the text in it, not the tag. However it might be a handy example. I will check it out.

Comment: In that case, just check nodeValue instead of nodeName like `if ($node->nodeValue == 'matching text')`

Comment: I have just double checked it. It works good except some nested elements such as `<ul><li>Text 1</li><li>Text 2</li></ul>` Once I get the output it has changed the text but there are no more `<li>` elements. Output was `<ul>Changed 1 Changed 2</ul>`. However `<section><div>Text 1 in Div</div></section>` is working just as I need it to be. Output is `<section><div>Changed Text 1 in Div</div></section>` Any ideas how to deal with `<ul>` elements? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For <li> tags, you can do, `foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('li') as $node) { ...do something here... }` If you know which tags to deal with, you can always use getElementsByTagName('tagname'). If you need to traverse all the elements without knowing which tags have some info you need to change, it's gonna be little bit more complicated. Take a look at this page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356115/traverse-the-dom-tree .